# Bind gridview using jquery : Have table data clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this part of code which is suppose to pass values from my dataset to a gridview.

```
 var row = $("[id*=gvPlastic] tr:last-child").clone(true);
 var codes = $(this).find("Code").text();
  if  ($(this).find("Stock").text() == 'Y') {
      $("td", row).eq(7).html('<a href="#" onclick="getStock()" value=' + codes + ' />' + codes + '</a>');
     }
      else {
       $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("Stock").text());
        }
```

How ever the variable code is outside the link i.e shown below:

```
<a value="80043" onclick="getStock()" href="#"></a>
80043
```

I am binding a gridview using jquery. My intention was the boundfield Stock be clickable if value is Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the anchor element in your code twice...

```
<a href="#" onclick="getStock()" value=' + codes + ' />' + codes + '</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getStock()" value=' + codes + '>' + codes + '</a>
```

(note the removed "/" right before the anchor's greater-than character)

Comment: TThanks a lot! Didn't notice that.